# Quick sort with multiple keys?

Tags: c++, quicksort

I need an full quick sort code for c++.
The department wants to have data sorted in this manner:

1. The data should be sorted considering the population.
2. However, if two residence has the same number of habitants, geo_id should be considered.
3. If both parts match, the code should decide which residence should appear first.

Please help me.
I kept the population as integer, `geo_id string.swap()` is my change function.
Object is the all of the my data

```
void habitant::quickSort(habitant& item,int left,int right){
int i = left;
int j = right;
int pivot = item.c_population[(left + right) / 2];

//partition
while (i <= j) {
    while (item.c_population[i] < pivot)
        i++;
    while (item.c_population[j] > pivot)
        j--;
    if (i <= j) {

        swap(item.c_population[i], item.c_population[j]);
        swap(item.c_object[i], item.c_object[j]);
        swap(item.c_geo_id[i], item.c_geo_id[j]);
        i++;
        j--;
    }

};

  //recursion
  if (left < j)
        quickSort(item, left, j);
  if (i < right)
        quickSort(item, i, right);
}
```

Comment: Please state clearly whether this is a homework assignment (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also, please learn about using markdown for formatting. Taking the [tour], especially [ask] would look good.

Comment: "if two residence has the same number of habitants, geo_id should be considered" --> In quicksort you **compare an element with pivot element** and take the decision of swapping it with another element as the quicksort partitions the given array around the picked pivot. In your algorithm, How do you come to know if two residence has the same number of habitants? Don't you think for this you need to compare the two elements with each other directly?

Comment: i read a csv file. i kept all of the inputs as vector<string> or vector<int>.and i kept lines as object.i send them into my class habitant.in my code i can sort them accoding to population but some of the populations are equals.so i need to sort according to geo_id if my populations are equals.so i need to use full quick sort code.i tried add some codes in if , but it didn't work.

Comment: instead of having a single object comprised of three vectors, why not have a vector of `struct habitant { string name; int population; int geo_id; }`? You can then use @H.S.'s comparison with `std::sort`

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother writing it yourself, use `std::sort`. That will take a custom sort order. From the comment, I understand that `habitant::operator<` does not sort on `geo_id`. That means your custom sort order function first checks `a<b` and `b<a`. If both are false, you return `a.geo_id < b.geo_id`.

(A sort order funtion, or *predicate* takes two arguments to be sorted and returns `true` *if and only if* the first argument sorts before the second)

Comment: the code is working but i need full sort.if my populations is equals,i need to sort according to my geo_id data.

Comment: @TugayAcar: Then you use `std::sort` with a custom sort order.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are sorting habitants according to the **population** and your requirement is - if the **population** is equal then sort according to **geo_id**. In you code you have:

```
while (item.c_population[i] < pivot)
```

and

```
while (item.c_population[j] > pivot)
```

Here you are only considering the **population** to sort the list of items and as a result, you are getting the list sorted based on **population**, which is obvious.

To solve your problem you need to consider multiple criteria's for comparison. Best approach is to write a `function` for comparison and use that function in your quicksort algorithm.
The function should have **multiple criteria's** for sorting and in your case the **multiple criteria's will be population (primary criteria) and geo_id (secondary criteria)**.

Something like this (function below is just a sample function to explain you and for your requirement, this may be altogether different):

```
int compare (habitant& item1, habitant& item2) {
    if (item.population < item2.population)
            return -1;      // item1 is smaller than item 2
    else if (item.population > item2.population)
            return 1;       // item 1 is bigger than item 2
    else if (item1.geo_id < item2.geo_id)
            return -1;      // item1 is smaller than item 2
    else if ((item1.geo_id > item2.geo_id)
            return 1;       // item 1 is bigger than item 2
    else
            return 0;       // both the items are same
}
```

Based on the return value of your `compare()` function take your decision to swap or not on your algorithm.